# Find the date in a week from a given day using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
const from = "2020-07-08";
const to = "2020-07-14";
```

How can I get the date of, let's say, "Thursday" inside a given week using moment.js?
In this example below, the expected answered would be "2020-07-09" for "Thursday" and "2020-07-12" for "Sunday" and so on.

Comment: moment can give you the number of the day: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/02-get-set/06-day/

Comment: @cybercoder close to what I'm looking for, but I want it after the given date, not before. `moment("2020-07-08", "YYYY-MM-DD").day("Sunday")` is returning `Sun Jul 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300`

Comment: Yes it will give on That Week you can check the day number and if it is in next week then add days to the date to being in next week.  (I got confused what i said but it seems correct ) :}

Comment: @cybercoder aha well I can add 7 days on it and it will work fine I guess, maybe there's another way to do this without "hacking"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let findNextWeekDay = (input_date,day)=> {
  let the_date = moment(input_date);
  if (the_date.day(day).isSameOrBefore(input_date)) {
     return the_date.day(day).add(7,'days');
  }
  return the_date.day(day)
}

console.log(findNextWeekDay("2021-06-20","Wednesday"));
console.log(findNextWeekDay("2021-06-22","Wednesday"));
console.log(findNextWeekDay("2021-06-23","Wednesday"));
console.log(findNextWeekDay("2021-06-26","Wednesday"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmmm, check it for all days please, i've doubt about the next half of the week or middle day.

Comment: Must check the number of day and make it conditional

Answer (score 2):

```
var new_date = moment("2020-07-08", "YYYY-MM-DD").add(5, 'days');
```

Comment: This is only true for "Monday". I want to get the date through using letters of the day, "Thursday", "Friday", etc

Comment: I'm not sure what you understood but I don't want the day in letters, I want the date from the day in letters.

Comment: ok got it so you want to query between two dates and want to output the date.
eg: 'monday' gives 2020-07-13. I think you can create your function which takes two ranges. an return the map of { [day]: date }.